# Sonar Plugin not compiling after package structure change

Tags: java, gwt, sonarqube, pom.xml

I am writing a Sonar GWT Plugin and since a change in the package structure the plugin no longer compiles. I changed the structure from

```
jku.se.drilldown.ui.client
```

to

```
jku.se.drilldown.client.ui
```

I adapted my pom.xml to this and also the gwt.xml file, but I always get this error:

```
[INFO] [ERROR] Unable to find type 'jku.se.drilldown.client.ui.BenchmarkViewerPanel'
[INFO] [ERROR] Hint: Previous compiler errors may have made this type unavailable
[INFO] [ERROR] Hint: Check the inheritance chain from your module; it may not be inheriting a required module or a module may not be adding its source
```

path entries properly

This is my pom.xml, and below the file BenchmarkViewer.gwt.xml in the folder resources/jku/se/drilldown/client. The plugin is in the package jku.se.drilldown, the viewer below that in client, and the actual gwt-panel below that in ui.

http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    4.0.0
    jku.se.drilldown
    sonar-benchmark-plugin
    sonar-plugin
    0.1-SNAPSHOT
    Sonar Benchmark Plugin

```
<properties>
    <sonar.buildVersion>2.11</sonar.buildVersion>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.sonar</groupId>
        <artifactId>sonar-plugin-api</artifactId>
        <version>${sonar.buildVersion}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.sonar</groupId>
        <artifactId>sonar-gwt-api</artifactId>
        <version>${sonar.buildVersion}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.sonar</groupId>
        <artifactId>sonar-core-gwt</artifactId>
        <version>${sonar.buildVersion}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.sonar</groupId>
        <artifactId>sonar-ws-client</artifactId>
        <version>${sonar.buildVersion}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
        <artifactId>gwt-user</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
        <artifactId>gwt-incubator</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- unit tests -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.sonar</groupId>
        <artifactId>sonar-testing-harness</artifactId>
        <version>${sonar.buildVersion}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.8.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.sonar</groupId>
            <artifactId>sonar-packaging-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <configuration>
                <pluginClass>jku.se.drilldown.BenchmarkPlugin</pluginClass>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <configuration>
                        <modules>
                            <module>jku.se.drilldown.client.BenchmarkViewer</module>
                        </modules>
                        <webappDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes</webappDirectory>
                        <extraJvmArgs>-Xmx512m</extraJvmArgs>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.5</source>
                <target>1.5</target>
                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>

    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                        <pluginExecutions>
                            <pluginExecution>
                                <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                                    <versionRange>[1.2,)</versionRange>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>compile</goal>
                                    </goals>
                                </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                <action>
                                    <execute />
                                </action>
                            </pluginExecution>
                            <pluginExecution>
                                <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <groupId>org.codehaus.sonar</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>sonar-packaging-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                                    <versionRange>[1.1,)</versionRange>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>check-dependencies</goal>
                                    </goals>
                                </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                <action>
                                    <execute />
                                </action>
                            </pluginExecution>


                        </pluginExecutions>
                    </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>

</build>
```

```
<inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.User' />
<inherits name="org.sonar.Sonar" />

<entry-point class='jku.se.drilldown.client.ui.BenchmarkViewerPanel' />

<extend-property name="locale" values="en" />
<extend-property name="locale" values="fr" />
```

I am building with maven. Hope someone has a tip for me, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If `BenchmarkViewer.gwt.xml` is in `….client`, then you have to add `<source path="ui"/>` or `<source path=""/>`, because the source path defaults to a `client` subpackage.

Either that or move `BenchmarkViewer.gwt.xml` up one leve (so that `client` *is* a subpackage)